# How to work with mulltiple readmore options in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have for categories with image and description fields. each description contains big text if it is more than 200 words, then should show `read more` link. On click on read more there should display full text with `readless` link also.
I tried the below code but if I click on 1st subcategory it opens all the `enter code here`categories readmore option link. if I click readless then it works for all other categories readless link. How to make each working seperate with readmore and readless links.

Here is my code

I have for categories with image and description fields. each description contains big text if it is more than 200 words, then should show `read more` link. On click on read more there should display full text with `readless` link also.
I tried the below code but if I click on 1st subcategory it opens all the `enter code here`categories readmore option link. if I click readless then it works for all other categories readless link. How to make each working seperate with readmore and readless links.

Here is my code

```
     import React,{useState} from 'react';
    
    export function FullReport(props) {
      const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState(false);
      const linkName = readMore ? "...Read Less" : "...Read More";
      const [categories, setcategories] = React.useState([]);
       
      React.useEffect(() => {
          try {
            axios
              .get(
                `/getReportDetails`
              )
              .then(
                (response) => {
                  console.log(response);
                  let serverData = response.data.data;
                  let categories = [];
                  serverData.categoryDetails.forEach((data) => {
                    categories.push(data);
                  });
                  setcategories(categories);
                },
              
              );
      
          } catch (e) {
          }
        }, [categories.length);
      
    return (
    <div>
        {categories.map((sitems, ssindex) => {
        <p>{sitems.name}</p>
        <p>
          {!readMore &&
            sitems?.description?.substring(
              0,
              201
            )}
          {readMore && sitems?.description}
          <Link
            to="#"
            className="read-more-link"
            onClick={() => {
              setReadMore(!readMore);
            }}
          >
            <>
              {sitems?.description?.length >
                201 && linkName}
            </>
          </Link>
        </p>
        }
   </div>
  )};
```

Comment: Do u want to open any one `read more` at a time, or multiple the read more??

Comment: I have to open one  read more at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created an example. You can refer to this code link

**multiple read ore opened at a time**

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/read-multi.js

**`Note:` go to `/read-multi` of `codesandbox Browser`**

---

**single read ore opened at a time**

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/read-single.js

**`Note:` go to `/read-single` of `codesandbox Browser`**

---

What you are doing is, are keeping a single state for reading more of all categories.

**for multi read**

You should have an individual state for each category and should only toggle that state when read more of particular category is clicked.
For individual ReadState, I have taken a boolean array State of size of categories.

---

**for single read**

You should have an `readState index` that is currently opened, and if you want to open any other, then reset the readMore index to the new index. otherwise set it to -1, for nothing open.

Comment: @ Himanshu Singh ,  I have description field for each categories. So if description length is greater than 201 , I have to show read more link. My pblm is if I any click any read more link in any description all other read more opens. And if I click read less all read less works.

Comment: Try this, you need to store the current open index, not the true or false. If the `current iterated category's index === current open index`, then it will show all the description otherwise not.

Comment: read the description and go through the code, you can easily understand.

Comment: you can mark this as an answer and close the question

Answer (score 1):

You should check index and manage states with your index instead of using single boolean. You chould fix it with object states easily like `const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState({isOpen: false, index: 0});`

But instead of implementing this solution I would create new component for this part

```
        <p>{sitems.name}</p>
        <p>
          {!readMore &&
            sitems?.description?.substring(
              0,
              201
            )}
          {readMore && sitems?.description}
          <Link
            to="#"
            className="read-more-link"
            onClick={() => {
              setReadMore(!readMore);
            }}
          >
            <>
              {sitems?.description?.length >
                201 && linkName}
            </>
          </Link>
        </p>
```

and return it in map function. You should put your state inside new component instead of using inside `FullReport` component and you can use it as boolean like you are using now

```
const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState(false);
```

@Evren , As per your suggestion my edited code is here, splitted into 2 components.but readmore links not works on click now.Kindly help me to rectify the error.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';

export function FullReport(props) {
  const [categories, setcategories] = React.useState([]);
   
  React.useEffect(() => {
      try {
        axios
          .get(
            `/getReportDetails`
          )
          .then(
            (response) => {
              console.log(response);
              let serverData = response.data.data;
              let categories = [];
              serverData.categoryDetails.forEach((data) => {
                categories.push(data);
              });
              setcategories(categories);
            },
          
          );
  
      } catch (e) {
      }
    }, [categories.length);
  



  const ProfileItem = (sitems) => {
      const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState(false);
      return (
              <div>
                <p>
                  {!readMore &&
                    sitems?.description?.substring(
                      0,
                      201
                    )}
                  {readMore && sitems?.description}
                    <Link to="#" className="read-more-link" onClick={() => setReadMore(!readMore);
                                        }}>
                  {readMore ? "Read Less" : "Read more"}
                </Link>
                </p>
              </div>
            )}
                                   


      return (
          <div>
              {categories.map((sitems, ssindex) => {
                  <ProfileItem {...sitems} />
            })}
           </div>        
            );
          };
```

I have created you a working example. In your refactoring you did not create a new component, you just created function inside react component. Here the code sandbox and the code

```
import React  from 'react';

export default function App(props) {
  const categories = [{description:'123456789'},
                      {description:'123456789'},
                      {description:'123456789'},
                      {description:'123456789'}]
   
      return (
          <div>
              {categories?.map((sitems, ssindex) => {
                return  <ProfileItem  sitems={sitems} />
                   
            })} 
           </div>        
            );
          };
export const ProfileItem = ({sitems}) => {
          const [readMore, setReadMore] = React.useState(false);
          return (
                  <div style={{border:'1px solid black', width: 300}} onClick={()=>setReadMore(!readMore)}>
                    <p  >
                    {!readMore &&
                    sitems?.description?.substring(
                      0,
                      5
                    )}
                  {readMore && sitems?.description} 
                    </p>
                  </div>
                )}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sound-j93lv?file=/src/App.js

Comment: As you per your suggestion ,I edited the above code by making 2 components. but now on click readmore buton not works. can you tell where i made wrong?

Comment: I have updated my answer @SreRoR